# How to get the current state when processing the onChange event from an input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I know that the react groups state updates to improve performance, but I need to get the current state, please tell me how can I do this?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const handleChange = e => {
    
    console.log(e.target.value, 'here is the desired state');
    setInputValue(e.target.value,'but here is always one step behind');
    console.log(inputValue); // I am outputting the log from the handler and this is not true. The state has changed and there is no error.
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" value={inputValue} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-onchange-3pond?file=/src/App.js:0-407

Comment: Don’t use onchange? Listen to key up or down instead?

Comment: `setInputValue()` is asynchronous as all state setting is in React. You can use `useEffect()` to track changes

Comment: @evolutionxbox I need a controlled component, key up or down will not change the input value

Comment: _What_ is one step behind?

Comment: Current state - `inputValue `
https://www.dropbox.com/s/72f28hppiu1k4oy/Screenshot%202020-06-07%20at%2003.46.10.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much torment, I realized that I can do like this

```
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    onSearch(inputValue)
  }, [inputValue, onSearch])

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value

    setInputValue(value)

    console.log('state', inputValue);

  }

  return (
    <div className={style.wrapper}>
      <FilterPanel onFilterItems={onFilterItems} stateFilter={stateFilter} />

      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={onInputChange}
        className={style.input}
        placeholder="search"
      />
    </div>
  )
```

callback in useEffect gives the desired result

Comment: what is ```onSearch``` ?

Answer (score -1):

like so :

```
  const handleChange = e => {

    console.log(e.target.value, 'here is the desired state');
    setInputValue(currentSate=>console.log(currentSate)); here you have access to current sate
    console.log(inputValue);
  };
```

and if you want to access newState change running useEffect with dependencies with that state will do the work:

```
useEffect(()=>console.log(inputValue),[inputValue])
```

this will run every time the inputValue change.

Comment: That won't set the new value